# live streaming with agora in nextjs, error UID_CONFLICT is reported

Tags: io

```js
if (userRole === 'audience') {
        client.setClientRole(userRole, {
          level: 2,
        });

        client.on('user-published', handleUserPublished);
        client.on('user-unpublished', handleUserUnpublished);
      } else {
        client.setClientRole('host');
      }
      client.on('user-joined', handleUserUJoined);
      client.on('user-left', handleUserLeft);

     
      try {
        const curUserId = await client.join(appId, channelName, rtcToken, uid);
        console.log('curUserId', curUserId, userRole);
        setJoin(true);

        if (userRole === 'host') {
          if (!videoTrack) {
            const localVideoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();
            setVideoTrack(localVideoTrack);
          }
          if (!audioTrack) {
            const localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({
              encoderConfig: 'music_standard',
            });
            setAudioTrack(localAudioTrack);
          }

          if (audioTrack && videoTrack) {
            await client.publish([audioTrack, videoTrack]);
          }

          videoTrack?.play(document.getElementById('#local-player')!);
          console.log('publish success');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      }
```

I registered a new account to join this live broadcast room, but it still prompts that UID has joined the live broadcast room; Also try to remove Uids and tokens but still have problems